# SQL Query field same ID

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mySQL table like this example:

```
ID | ProcID | Value    
1  | 6      | one   
1  | 7      | two    
1  | 8      | three    
1  | 9      | four    
2  | 6      | one    
2  | 7      | two   
2  | 8      | three   
2  | 9      | four
```

I need to get only the ID #1 and the value from the ProcID 6 and 7.. how can I do with only one PHP query?
I already did with two separate queries but I'm sure is possible with only one, maybe with some parameters such "ON" or "IN" but I didn't find anything!

Comment: $one=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1 AND ProcID=6");
$row_one = mysql_fetch_assoc($one);
$val_one=$row_one['value']

And the same with se ProcID 7

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE ID = 1 AND ProcID IN (6,7)
```

Sample result:

```
ID | ProcID | Value
--------------------
1  | 6      | one
1  | 7      | two
```

Comment: my answer completely missed that

Comment: Thanks... in PHP? How can I print the results?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to select the only ID of 1 from `ProcID` use :

```
SELECT * FROM `table` where `ID` = '1' AND `ProcID` = '6' AND `ProcID` = '7'
```

Comment: Think about it twice. Can ProcID be 7 AND 6 at the same time ?